# Q: Unable to return a specific attribute from an object List?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a list of events that contains multiple attributes such as id, name and etc... I am unable to print the 'id' from event.

```
final data = Provider.of<Events>(context);
print(data.items.where((element) => event.id));
```

For example, the output should be e1,e2,e3.

Data file:

```
List<Event> _items = [
Event(
  id: 'e1',
  address: 'address 1',
  title: 'Event1',
),
Event(
  id: 'e2',
  address: 'address 2',
  title: 'Event2',
),
Event(
  id: 'e3',
  address: 'address 3',
  title: 'Event3',
),
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
print(_items.map((i) => i.id).join(','));
```